# Get span text Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to retrieve a span text -cnn.com from the below structure using jquery.

```js
var txt = $(".example1 >.myNewTest").closest('.subexample2').find('span').text();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example1" id="test1">
  <div id="wkTest" class="myNewTest">
    <h2 class="subexample2">
      <span class="moreTest></span>
      <span>cnn.com</span>---->I need this.
      <span>/</span>
      <span>News</span>
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing the closing quote of `class="moreTest"`. Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: `.closest()` goes *up* the DOM hierarchy, but `.subexample2` is below `.myNewTest`. Use `.find()` to select a descendant.

Comment: There are multiple spans in `.subexample2`. Since the one you want doesn't have a class, you'll need to use its index: `.find("span").eq(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have the option to add a class name or ID to the element, you can try this one below. + selector targets immediate sibling element.

```
var txt = $(".example1 >.myNewTest > .subexample2 > .moreTest + span").text();
```

Well if you can add a class then it would be much simpler, check the below code. website is the class name used to target the element.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example1" id="test1">
  <div id="wkTest" class="myNewTest">
    <h2 class="subexample2">
      <span class="moreTest"></span>
      <span class="website">cnn.com</span>
      <span>/</span>
      <span>News</span>
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>

var txt = $(".example1 .website").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple span elements, a good way to differentiate them is by adding an id to the span you want to retrieve. Once you have done this, it is easy to retrieve the text using .innerHTML.

```js
var cnn = $('#cnn')[0].innerHTML
console.log(cnn)
```

```html
<div class="example1" id="test1">
  <div id="wkTest" class="myNewTest">
    <h2 class="subexample2">
      <span class="moreTest"></span>
      <span id="cnn">cnn.com</span>
      <span>/</span>
      <span>News</span>
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the span with the text you want is always the 2nd child of element with class `subexample2` you can use:

```js
const txt = $('.example1 > .myNewTest > .subexample2 > span:eq(1)').text()
```

```js
const txt = $('.example1 > .myNewTest > .subexample2 > span:eq(1)').text()

$('#result').val(txt)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="example1" id="test1">
  <div id="wkTest" class="myNewTest">
    <h2 class="subexample2">
      <span class="moreTest"></span>
      <span>cnn.com</span>
      <span>/</span>
      <span>News</span>
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="result">
```

Comment: I have added a class and now my structure looks like this:

Comment: <div class="example1" id="test1">
  <div id="wkTest" class="myNewTest">
    <h2 class="subexample2">
      <span class="moreTest"></span>
      <span class="NameId">cnn.com</span>
      <span>/</span>
      <span>News</span>
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: The DOM inspection looks like this: div.example1>div.myNewTest>h2.subexample2>div.moreTest>span.NameId

Comment: I am doing like this and still can't  get the text cnn.com

Comment: $('.example1').each(function () {
             

            var el = $(this).closest('.moreTest').find('span.NameId').text();    
                          
            
        });